# How can i achieve universal same offset value drag position in different screen devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I trying to achieve a draggable and scalable text composable using pointerInput modifier and graphics modifier. for example, if i drag and place the text composable in a middle of Box composable of width(350.dp) and height(250.dp) and get the value OffsetX and OffSetY  in one device and set the same and check with a bigger screen devices it's not placed in middle position of the Box composable of the other device screen position. how can i achieve a universal same position set across all device screens when the offsetValues is set in any screen device.

My code

```
 var tittleScale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
 var tittleRotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
 var parentSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
 var draggableContentSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }

             editSurfaceModifier = Modifier
            .width(rectangleSurfaceShapeWidth)
            .height(rectangleSurfaceShapeHeight)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .transformable(state = state)
            .onPlaced { layoutCoordinates ->
                parentSize = layoutCoordinates.size.toSize()
            }

  if (tittleTap) {
    state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
        tittleScale *= zoomChange
        tittleRotation += rotationChange

    }
}

   Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {   
     Box(
        modifier = editSurfaceModifier
    )
    {  
        if (tittleTapVisible) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
            ) {

                Text(
                    text = "BrandTittle",
                    color = customEditState.tittleTextColor,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onPlaced { draggableContentSize = it.size.toSize() }
                        .offset {

                            IntOffset(
                                x = tittleOffsetX.roundToInt(),
                                y = tittleOffsetY.roundToInt()
                            )
                        }

                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectTapGestures(
                                onTap = {
                                    showingZoomText = "TittleTapped"
                                    tittleTap = true
                                },
                                onLongPress = {
                                    haptics.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
                                    customString = "TittleText"
                        }
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectDragGestures(
                                onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                    viewModel.onEvent(CustomEditEvent.ResetText(false))
                                    change.consume()
                                    tittleOffsetX = (tittleOffsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn(
                                        minimumValue = 0f,
                                        maximumValue = parentSize.width - draggableContentSize.width
                                    )
                                    tittleOffsetY = (tittleOffsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(
                                        minimumValue = 0f,
                                        maximumValue = parentSize.height - draggableContentSize.height
                                    )

                                },
                                onDragStart = { offset ->
                                    showingDraggedText = "Changed"

                                }, onDragEnd = {
                                    showingDraggedText = "Drag End"
                                })
                        }
                        .graphicsLayer(
                            scaleX = tittleScale,
                            scaleY = tittleScale,
                            rotationZ = tittleRotation,
                        )
                )
                val offsetXDp = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                    tittleOffsetX.toDp()
                }

                val offsetYDp = with(LocalDensity.current) {
                    tittleOffsetY.toDp()
                }

                Log.i (TAG,"Offset values: X:$offsetXDp,.. Y:$offsetYDp")
                Log.i (TAG,"Offset orginal values: X:$tittleOffsetX,.. Y:$tittleOffsetY")
```

[image: example]

I tried with LocalDenisty.current but not sure how to work with this